# Can a third country citizen with temporary residence permit in Croatia travel to EU freely?

Tags: eu, residence-cards

I have a temporary residence permit for Croatia.  Can I travel to other EU countries, such as Germany?

What other advantages do I have with this card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a temporary residence permit for Croatia. Can I travel to other EU countries, such as Germany?

The Croatian permit does not exempt you from the requirement to have a visa to enter the Schengen area.  So, assuming you're not traveling with an Annex II passport, and you have no other basis for a visa exemption, you can only travel to Germany if you get a Schengen visa.

> What other advantages do I have with this card?

I am not aware of any.  If Croatia joins the Schengen area while the card is still valid, however, it will allow you to visit other Schengen countries, subject to the 90/180 rule.  According to Wikipedia, this [might happen next year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area#Prospective_members).

Comment: Should note that this means just "travel", not taking residence in another country. So you could go on holiday to Spain, for example, but not take a job in Spain.

Comment: @gnasher729 do you suspect that readers might understand "travel" to mean something other than "travel"?

Comment: If they want to travel to another country and stay there, they will understand "travel" as "travel and stay", absolutely. And for example UK immigration interprets "permission to travel to the UK" as "permission to travel to the UK and return home" and gets difficult if they think the traveller thinks "travel" doesn't include "return home".

Comment: @gnasher729 okay, that's a bit pedantic, and I doubt that many would see it that way, but if I've learned nothing else from this site it's that any given misinterpretation of a text is bound to be followed by someone, so I've changed "travel to" to "visit" and added an explicit mention of the 90/180 rule.  Do you find it clearer?